# Require akka in module-info.java

Tags: java, akka, java-9, java-module, module-info

What do I have to require in `module-info.java` to use `Akka` with `JDK 9`?
I have following dependency in `maven`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
  <artifactId>akka-actor_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `jar --file=akka-actor-<version>.jar --describe-module` should tell you.

Comment: @AlanBateman I typed you command but now I get
  `Unable to derive module descriptor for: akka-actor_2.12-2.5.6.jar 
 akka.actor.2.12: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier`

Comment: Unfortunately you are out of luck due to the odd name of this JAR file. The reason the module name is derived from the JAR file name is because the JAR file does not an explicit module (no module-info.class) and the maintainers have not reserved a module name yet by adding an Automatic-Module-Name attribute to the main manifest. A post to the akka mailing list might give some indication when or if they are planning to do anything in this area.

Comment: We plan to explicitly add the `Automatic-Module-Name` property to the manifest for the next release (2.5.7), that should make this simpler: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23931